# How is this stepping down 12 V?

Tags: voltage, step-down

I'm positive that the microcontroller (U3) in the picture can only receive a 5 V input. I just want to know how those components (the two resistors and the capacitor by In1) are stepping down the 12 V voltage to 5 V.

[image: :)]

I found another photo, sorry for the quality:

[image: :(]

Comment: Chip is voltage stabilizer.

Comment: which chip are you referring to?

Comment: `those components` ... what components are you referring to?

Comment: The two reisstors and the capacitor under the IN 1 pin

Comment: My comment was made then you posted one picture. At this picture only two chips. One is MCU. So U2 is voltage stabilizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, it appears you are talking about this part of the board:

[image]

Those are inputs going to a microprocessor, not the power input for the board or the processor.

If you untangle the circuit, it looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1OLaw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit is basically a [voltage divider (R2 and R7)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) which brings down the input 12V signal to 5V.  The diode is there to protect the input from negative voltage while the capacitor will catch higgh voltage spikes and reduce noise.

The values I chose for R2 and R7 are representative.  Any pair of resistors with the same ratio will do.

You will want to keep them relatively high, though.  They depend on the clamping diode in the microprocessor to clip the voltage if the input is more than about 12.7V.  The clamp diode can't handle much current, so you want R2 to be large enough that any expected higher voltage at the input won't exceed the current rating of the clamp diode in the microprocessor.

I've shown the diode as a Schottky part.  It may be a Zener instead, rated for 5V.  If it is a Zener, then it will protect the microprocessor against over voltage as well as reverse voltage.

The diode inside the dotted line is the clamp diode on the microprocessor.  It will short anything above about 5.3V to the 5V supply of the processor to protect the circuit inside from overvoltage.

---

The diode protects the processor from negative voltage because when the input is lower than 0V then the diode will conduct.

In normal operation, the diode doesn't conduct.  Any time the input is 0V or higher, the diode is shutoff.

The current flow looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0gpZb.png)</sup>

When the input goes below 0V, the diode cathode is "more positive" than the input.

The current flow looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFNEg4.png)</sup>

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'm just trying to understand how the diode D1 protects the circuit from negative voltage

Comment: Thank you again for helping me

Answer (score 5):

The IC in the SOT-89 package (upper right, 3 pins plus a tab) appears to be a linear voltage regulator, judging by the large ceramic capacitors C2 and C3 on input and output. Perhaps similar to an LM78M05, however your cropping and low photo quality makes it hard to tell the numbers.

How does it do it? It adjusts its internal pass element so that enough voltage (about 7V) is dropped inside the part to give 5V out, and turns that into heat. So efficiency will be less than 42%.

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiWs3L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There are multiple inputs going to the microcontroller, if they all go through the voltage regulator how does the microcontroller figure out which ones are "High"

Comment: I'm pretty sure the regulator is for powering the microcontroller

Comment: The other parts are probably zener diodes to limit the input voltage (in conjunction with a series resistor) to a voltage acceptable to the MCU.

Comment: so this circuit is a combination of a voltage divider with resistors in series and a zener voltage divider?

Comment: The resistor across the zener diode, I would surmise, is to ensure that the input is a logic 0 when open. It does not function as a voltage divider. In other words if you calculated 12V * R2/(R1+R2) it would be more than 5V. Consider it a pull-down.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

The next three-pin IC is a voltage regulator. In particular, the LM7805 with its two filtering and smoothing capacitors.